# Excel Vb check value i worksheets error

Tags: vba, excel

I try to check if a value  in column "B" in sheet2  also is in column "B"  sheet1, if there is a match then i want a "1" in the column 5, if not  a "0"

I have the following code but doesnot do the job

```
Dim S1 As Worksheet
Dim S2 As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set S1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set S2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

k = S1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
j = S2.UsedRange.Rows.Count



For i = 1 To k
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(S2.Range("B", j), S1.Range("B", k)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Found"
    S1.Cells(i, 5).Value = "1"
Else
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    S1.Cells(i, 5).Value = "0"
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Do you want to compare same rows?

Comment: No in sheet2 are less rows then in sheet1, value  in sheet2 it always in sheet1. But a value in sheet1 doesnot always is in sheet2

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wk As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long
Dim strA As String, strB As String
Dim FRowA As Long, FRowB As Long

'Setting Worksheet Variables
Set wk = Sheet1
Set ws = Sheet2

m = wk.Rows.count
FRowA = wk.Range("B" & m).End(xlUp).Row     
FRowB = ws.Range("B" & m).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To FRowB
    strB = Trim(ws.Range("B" & i).Text)
        For j = 1 To FRowA
                strA = Trim(wk.Range("B" & j).Text)
                    If strA = strB Then

                        wk.range("E"&j).Value = 1 

                    Else End If         
         Next j
Next i              

     For j = 1 To FRowA
     strA = Trim(wk.Range("E" & j).Text)
     If strA = "" Then

     wk.range("E"&j).Value = 0

     Else End If         
     Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank this works, for some reason there a empty rows in both sheets, so thats match and the value is then "1"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confusing the cell reference syntax for a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and a [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx). The syntax is closer to `S2.Range("B" & j)` , not `S2.Range("B", j)` ; but that does not cover full columns. It also doesn't appear that you are using the  [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) properly. In any event, a worksheet [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is more efficient.

```
For i = 1 To k
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(S1.Range("B"& i), S2.Range("B:B"), 0)) Then
        MsgBox "Found"
        S1.Cells(i, 5).Value = "1"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
        S1.Cells(i, 5).Value = "0"
    End If
Next
```

I think that should be closer to what you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you might be better served to do this with formulas directly, rather than VBA.

Let's start on Sheet2.  You have a value in cell B2. 
If that value appears anywhere in column B on Sheet1, you want to show the value 1 in cell E2 (same row, column 5).  If not, you want E2 to show a 0.

Since you want to show the result of a calculation in a single cell, a worksheet formula can do what you need. 
The MATCH function will look for the first match in a range, which is closer to your goal than COUNTIF.

If MATCH returns any number, it found a match, so we can use ISNUMBER to check the MATCH result and return a TRUE/FALSE. Finally, we can use IF to convert that to our custom output (in this case, 1 or 0).

In cell E2, enter this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B2,Sheet1!$B:$B,0)),1,0)
```

You can copy or fill that formula down as many rows as you want.  You won't need to enable macros in the workbook to use this, and your results will recalculate whenever the worksheet does (so you don't need to manually run a macro).

If you need to use VBA for a specific reason, it looks like other answers have already been posted.